Show $\zeta(2) = 1 + \sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{s+1} \zeta(s)$
Claim
I'm trying to show the Riemann zeta function for $s=2$ can be expressed as:
$$
\zeta(2) = 1 + \sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{s+1} \zeta(s)
$$
For example, this expands as:
$$
\zeta(2) = 1 + \zeta(3) - \zeta(4) + \zeta(5) - \zeta(6) + \cdots
$$
Proof
Starting from the known formula
$$
1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (n+1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
we focus on the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}
$$
We can express $\frac{1}{(n+1)}$ using its Taylor expansion around $\frac{1}{n}$. This follows from the identity
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}
$$
Applying the Taylor Series expansion $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots $, we set $x = \frac{1}{n}$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n+1} 
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^3} + \cdots \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^4} + \cdots
\end{align*}
Substituting the expansion into $\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)} 
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3} - \cdots \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^5} - \cdots
\end{align*}
Therefore, WolframAlpha shows
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)} 
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^5} - \cdots \right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^s \frac{1}{n^s} \\
&= 1 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align*}
Regularization Step: Interchanging summations, WolframAlpha evaluates the result as:
$$
\sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^s \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = 1 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
This summation does not converge in the classical sense, but WolframAlpha applies regularization techniques (likely involving the limiting case of the digamma function, as explained in the answer) to assign a finite value to the divergent series.
Substituting the Basel problem
$$
\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
and the Riemann zeta function
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}
$$
we use WolframAlpha to verify that:
$$
\zeta(2) = 1 + \sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{s+1} \zeta(s) \quad \blacksquare
$$
As noted in the comments, a simplified form is
$$
\boxed{\large \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} (-1)^s \zeta(s) = 1}
$$
Question
I'm not very familiar with general sequences and series (convergence, decay rates, ...) and how they interact with the Riemann Zeta function or even if this result is already well known. But, I've used WolframAlpha Pro (for students) extensively so does that make the proof less rigorous?
$$
\zeta(2) = 1 + \zeta(3) - \zeta(4) + \zeta(5) - \zeta(6) + \cdots
$$

Do you have any insight into how WA establishes those sums? I let my Pro account lapse, so I don't have step-by-step. If you don't see how WA does it, it's impossible in my opinion to say how rigorous this proof is.

There's no step-by-step, mostly just more digits.

More digits? As in the decimal expansion? That doesn't really tell us how it did the summation. I generally trust WA not to say the summation is (some exact form) unless it was able to establish that firmly. The question is how it established that. (You need a special account type for the step-by-step.)

Incidentally, this identity, if true, feels more natural to me written as $\sum_{s=2}^\infty (-1)^s \zeta(s) = 1$. That's just a personal preference though.

@StevenClark: It clearly doesn't converge absolutely, but with the alternating signs, it could converge conditionally, couldn't it? Am I missing something, perhaps? I mean really the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(2k)-\zeta(2k+1)$, I guess! (It is a bit odd that WA doesn't complain about that though.)

@BrianTung Since $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty} \zeta(s)=1$ the sum $\sum\limits_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{s+1}, \zeta(s)$ doesn't converge (see this contradictory Wolfram evaluation). How can it converge when as $s\to\infty$ the sum term alternates between $\pm 1$?

@StevenClark: As I added to my comment, I'm cheating a bit: I'm defining $a(k) = \zeta(2k)-\zeta(2k+1)$ and summing $a(k)$ for $k = 1$ to $\infty$. I agree that it can't converge as written. Not sure what WA is thinking there, which is partly why I asked if the OP could see the step-by-step.

@BrianTung I believe this evaluation of $\sum\limits_{k=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}, (\zeta (k)-1)=\zeta(2)-\frac{3}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{3}{2}$ makes more sense.

@StevenClark: I'll buy that. But how does WA arrive at that result?

@StevenClark How valid is breaking your mentioned summation, and then interpreting that alternating sum of $1$s as a cesaro sum? This derives the identity OP wants (but not strictly, it's probably a cesaro sum too but I would need to rigorously verify that).

@BrianTung I suspect the WolframAlpha evaluation is based on the identity $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n (\zeta (n)-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ found in formula (118) at MathWorld: Riemann Zeta Function which also contains numerous other identities for sums involving $\zeta(n)$.

@StevenClark: Ahh OK, thanks for that!

@YuzurihaInori I'm not sure I understand your approach, but I've noticed $$\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=3}^{2 K-1} (-1)^{k+1}, \zeta(k)\right)\approx\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{2}\tag{1}$$ $$\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=3}^{2 K} (-1)^{k+1}, \zeta(k)\right)\approx\zeta(2)-\frac{3}{2}\tag{2}$$ and $$\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum\limits_{k=3}^{K-1} (-1)^{k+1}, \zeta(k)+\sum\limits_{k=3}^K (-1)^{k+1}, \zeta(k)\right)\approx\zeta(2)-1\tag{3}$$ which are perhaps exact relationships.

Of course $\zeta(s) \to 1$ as $s \to\infty$, so [in the usual sense] the series $\sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{s+1} \zeta(s)$ diverges.

Wolfram seems to be evaluating a limiting case of the power series expansion of the digamma function, $\psi(z)$:
Starting from this expansion of the digamma function:
$$\psi(z) = -\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{z}{n(z+n)}\right] \quad \Re(z)>0$$
Now, if we restrict $|\Re(z)|<1$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi(z) = -\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2\left(\frac{z}{n}+1\right)} &=&  -\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2\left(\frac{z}{n}+1\right)} \\
&=& -\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^j\frac{z^j}{n^j}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^j\frac{z^j}{n^j}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{z}-\gamma+z\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{j+2}} (-1)^{j}z^{j}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{z}-\gamma-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\zeta(j+2) (-1)^{j+1}z^{j+1}\\
&=&-\frac{1}{z}-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta(k+1) (-1)^{k}z^{k}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
So, if $z \to 1^{-}$ then $ \psi(1) = -\gamma $ and:
$$ \lim_{z\to 1^{-}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\zeta(k+1) (-1)^{k}z^k = -1 \implies  \zeta(2) = 1+ \lim_{z\to 1^{-}} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\zeta(k+1) (-1)^{k}z^{k} $$
However, the result of your sum $ \displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$ is correct:
note that
$$ \psi(x)-\psi(y) =(x-y) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1+x)(n-1+y)}$$
Differentiating with respect to x:
$$ \psi^{(1)}(x) = (x-y)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1+x)^2(n-1+y)} + \frac{\psi(x)-\psi(y)}{x-y}$$
Now put $x=1,y=2$ and using the fact that $\displaystyle \psi^{(1)}(1) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}  = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$

There's a typo here: $ \sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, it should be $\sum \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}$, right? Also, is this answer saying the proof is valid? It's way too complex for me to understand. Thanks!

Hi, yes, that was a typo. What the answer shows is what Wolfram may have calculated for $\sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^s \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$. The series does not converge, but the value can be obtained as a limit of the digamma expansion series.

I am not an expert in analysis, but to me, the most natural way to make sense of the sum is to just remove the constant $1$ from each term to get the convergent series
$$
\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} (-1)^s ( \zeta(s) - 1 ).
$$
By expanding the definition of $\zeta(s)$, this equals
$$
\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^s}{n^s}.
$$
Switching the order of summation (absolute convergence holds), yields:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^s}{n^s}.
$$
Now the inner sum is simply a geometric series;
$$
\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^s}{n^s} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}.
$$
Therefore the full sum evaluates to
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Pulling out the first term now yields
$$
\zeta(2) = \frac{3}{2} - \sum_{s=3}^{\infty} (-1)^{s} ( \zeta(s) - 1 ).
$$
Alternatively, you can regroup the terms in your sum and analogously obtain the converging series
$$
\zeta(2) = \frac{3}{2} + \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} ( \zeta(2s - 1) - \zeta(2s) ).
$$
Both of these equalities can be verified numerically.
It surprises me that regularisation arguments produce a value that is $1/2$ off the answer one would "expect". This might be caused by this regularisation method somewhere assigning the value $1/2$ to the infinite sum $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 \pm \ldots$, which is the sole obstruction to the series you wrote down actually converging, but I am not sure about that. Still, I am certain that what I wrote down all has meaning, so that's worth something.

Nice variation and it keeps things classical without regularization methods, plus I actually followed your proof! Although, it could probably be shortened using this known result (118) which shows $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n (\zeta (n)-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. I'm an amateur with simple ideas, so I value your ideas and the community, a lot more. Anyhow, the goal was to express $\zeta(2)$ in terms of higher order $\zeta$ terms, which you've done. :)

Show
$$
\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} (-1)^s \zeta(s) = 1
$$
Proof
Restating
$$
\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} (-1)^s \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \zeta(n+1)
$$
The DLFM 5.15.2 shows the Polygamma function
$$
\psi^{(n)}(1) = (-1)^{n+1} n! \zeta(n+1)
$$
Solving for $\zeta(n+1)$ gives
$$
\zeta(n+1) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} \psi^{(n)}(1)
$$
Substituting gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \zeta(n+1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!} \psi^{(n)}(1) \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(n)}(1)}{n!}
$$
The Taylor series of the digamma function is defined as
$$\psi{(s)} = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(n)}(1) (s-1)^n}{n!}$$
Set $s=2$ and $\psi(1)=-\gamma$ (Euler–Mascheroni constant)
$$
\psi(2) = \psi(1) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(n)}(1)}{n!}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(n)}(1)}{n!} = \psi(2) - \psi(1)
$$
The Digamma recurrence relation states
$$
\psi(x+1) = \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x}
$$
Set $x = 1$
$$
\psi(2) - \psi(1) = 1
$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{s=2}^{\infty} (-1)^s \zeta(s) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \zeta(n+1) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\psi^{(n)}(1)}{n!} \\
&= \psi(2) - \psi(1) \\
&= 1 \quad \blacksquare
\end{align*}
